# Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on Exact Match

Tags: google-analytics, spreadsheet, add-on

When i use this filter code

```
 {
  "dimensionFilterClauses": [{
    "filters": [
      {
        "dimensionName": "ga:productSku",
        "operator": "REGEXP",
        "expressions": "(FS170)|(FS160)"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

FS17007
FS1701
FS17011
FS160
FS1602
FS16012

It show's all product skus that contains "FS170" or "FS160" how can i match multiple sku's Exact with a regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the start (`^`) and end (`$`) delimiters so that there can be nothing else than what you specify (`start`-`what i want`-`end`), thus the exact match:

```
"^(FS170|FS160)$"
```